# Navigation bar title is stuck

Tags: ios, swiftui, keyboard, toolbar

If I use a toolbar for the keyboard which has a `ScrollView` inside it messes up the navigation bar title which will just be positioned stuck at the screen instead of moving in the navigation bar.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

(Xcode 13.4.1)

Minimal reproducible code:

```
struct MyApp: App {
        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var numbers = Array(1...100).map { String($0) }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List($numbers, id: \.self) { $number in
                TextField("", text: $number)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Hello")
                            Text("World")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Messed up title")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Messed up title]

Comment: Just remove that Scrollview and then it should work fine

Comment: I need the scroll.

Comment: Ok Check my edited answer that will solve your issue, You can draw border line if you want any formatting in UI

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to add 100 toolbar item elements inside your keyboard which is causing performance issue and impacting on your navigation bar which could be issue in lower Xcode version compatibility. if you want to show 100 toolbar item elements then instead of adding inside keyboard add separate View and add on top of it and then based on keyboard appear or disappear hide/show 100 elements view accordingly. So I modify your code which is adding two toolbar items elements inside your keyboard and that seems to be working fine without any navigation title stuck issue eg below:-

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List($numbers, id: \.self) { $number in
                TextField("", text: $number)
            }.toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                    HStack {
                        Button("Cancel") {
                            print("Pressed")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Done") {
                            print("Pressed")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Messed up title")
        }
    }
```

> Edited Answer if you want to use ScrollView, instead of using List use ScrollView like below
> Please note this changes are required only if you are using lower Xcode version prior than Xcode 14

```
var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach($numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                    VStack {
                        TextField("", text: number)
                    }
                    }
                }.toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Hello")
                                Text("World")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationTitle("Messed up title")
            }
        }
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter because the ToolbarItem takes a ©ViewBuilder closure of View. The result is same with `ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) { ScrollView(.horizontal) { HStack { Text("Hello") } } }`